# Can you use TestNG's dataprovider with JBehave?

Tags: java, testng, bdd, dataprovider, jbehave

I'm looking for a BDD library that will work with TestNG (this is important because we already have a configured CI server that is integrated with TestNG).  I found JBehave but want to know if it is possible to use features such as TestNG's data provider.  Can someone with experience of these combined technologies show me how it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBehave has its own [mechanism for writing parameterized](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parametrised-scenarios.html) tests. I recommend using that, rather than combining JBehave with TestNG's DataProvider feature.